# How to open and activate BIM 360 document with Revit 2018?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I want to OpenAndActivateDocument that is kept on BIM360, but I am getting an error as "Document does not exist".

The same method is working with Revit 2019 flawlessly.

```
if (RevitObject.rvtUiDoc.Document.IsWorkshared)
{
       ModelPath MyCentralFile = doc.GetWorksharingCentralModelPath();

       if (MyCentralFile != null)
       {
            OpenOptions openoptions = new OpenOptions();

            RevitObject.rvtUiApp.OpenAndActivateDocument(MyCentralFile, 
            openoptions, false);


            RevitObject.rvtUiDoc.ActiveView = activeView;

            if (otherDoc != null)
                otherDoc.Close(false);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is not supported in the Revit API in 2018- only 2019+.

Unfortunate but true.